# how to setup a virtual host in apache to same server url of some port 

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

i want to setup a virtual host to the url of with some port

e.g. my server name is rockstar.net

so i want to setup a subdomain on my server.where i should access the content of http://rockstart.net:8001/

what i tried :

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName content.rockstart.net
  DocumentRoot "http://rockstart.net:8001/"

</VirtualHost>
```

which is giving error

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/http:/rockstar.net:8001/] does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

The DocumentRoot points to the folder in the local folder structure where the site is hosted, e.g. (on a linux system) /var/www/html/rockstart.net.
The port number must be included in the VirtualHost definition. Therefore your VHost definition should rather look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
  ServerName content.rockstart.net
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/rockstart.net"

</VirtualHost>
```

However, this will still require the users to enter http://rockstart.net:8001 into their browser. I suspect what you had in mind was actually more like a redirection. If the redirection needs to include a change of port (i.e. from 8001 to 80) then you either need to use a reverse proxy or a DNAT firewall.

Or, if the content that is to be made available under http://content.rockstart.net is located on the same server where rockstart.net is located, you could simply use a

```
<Location>
```

redirection within the file system. However, in that case I wonder why you don't just point content.rockstart.net at the same location where rockstart.net:8001 gets its content from?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:8001>
  ServerName content.rockstart.net
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/rockstart.net"

</VirtualHost> is not working how to use location tag ?

Comment: Well, where is the relevant content located, i.e. what is the DocumentRoot for the VHost running http://rockstart.net:8001? For the explanation on how to use the <Location> directive, read the Apache manual (I presume this is what you are using).

Comment: the content of rockstart.net:8001 is coming from node.js server

Comment: @Rahul Are you setting up a production server?

Comment: I am sorry, @Rahul, but your last comment doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever. Is the content on the same machine or not? And if yes, what is its location?

Comment: @wolfgangsz content is in the home directory not in www directory

Comment: Well, in that case use DocumentRoot "/home/<username>/<foldername>" in your vhost definition for content.rockstart.net.

Answer (score 0):

The `DocumentRoot` directives describes the physical path on the machine, like `/var/www/myvhost.net`.

Set this directive as a path and use `ServerName` for the first and `ServerAlias` for every other name you want to point to your files, defined in `DocumentRoot`.